# Too many futex() calls

Tags: linux, futex

We are observing unusual delays in one of our Java apps on a Linux RedHat machine while trying to publish to an external MQ queue (It never happened before). Did a quick health check on the box and the CPU/memory usage seems quite alright. The MQ boxes are quite fine as well. Restarted my Java process, no luck! We grabbed a quick `strace` snapshot after that and it is full of `futex()` calls.

Was wondering if somebody could give any clues on why so many locks could be happening (I know it is a very wide open kind of question. Depends on what the app actually does).

But I was hoping to get some more insight into the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So did you actually profile it and determined that futex calls are the bottleneck?

Assuming you did, one thing might be that a futex() syscall implies that the mutex is contended; FUTEX = fast user space mutex, uncontended mutexes are handled in user-space without a syscall. That is, you might have a problem with lock contention.